# Any idea why this user defined literals fails?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

I have the following code which implements the adler32 checksum:

```
constexpr uint32_t adler32(std::string_view sv)
{
    constexpr const uint32_t MOD_ADLER= 65521;
    uint32_t rv= 0, a= 1, b= 0;
    for (unsigned char c:sv)
    {
        a= (a+c)%MOD_ADLER;
        b= (b+a)%MOD_ADLER;
    }
    rv= a|(b<<16);
    return rv;
}

//----------------------------------------------------
constexpr uint16_t operator ""_csum(const char* str,long unsigned len)
{
    return adler32(std::string_view(str,len));
}
```

and the following test routine:

```
#include "adler32.h"
using easyUtils::operator""_csum;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto i= easyUtils::adler32("hello");
    auto j= "hello"_csum;
    auto k= easyUtils::adler32("hello");
    cout << i << '\t' << j  << '\t' << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output when compiled for `std=c++17` using either clang or g++ under Linux:

```
./test/adlerTest
103547413   533 103547413
```

I would have expected 103547413 three times.  Any ideas why this is not so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
constexpr uint16_t operator ""_csum
              ^^
```

And

```
103547413L % 65536L == 533L
```

Comment: Yes that should have bee uint32_t.  Thank you, that was driving me crazy.